# Darkflow: why am I getting lossy/incomplete output images ( I trained with my own data )

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-recognition, yolo, darkflow

I have trained darkflow yolo with my own data, the description of dataset:

> dataset size: 3 images
>   classes:1
>   classname: coca-cola

edited the yolo.cfg file to be yolo_custom.cfg:

> classes = 1
>   filters = 30

command to train:

```
python3 flow --model cfg/yolo_custom.cfg --load bin/yolo.weights --batch 1 --epoch 30 --train --annotation train_imgs/Annotations --dataset train_imgs/Images
```

result:

> Finish 29 epoch(es)
>   step 88 - loss 161.10618591308594 - moving ave loss 169.31837991674482
>   step 89 - loss 159.54132080078125 - moving ave loss 168.34067400514846
>   step 90 - loss 162.15159606933594 - moving ave loss 167.7217662115672
>   Finish 30 epoch(es)
>   Checkpoint at step 90
>   Training finished, exit.

to collect the new weights, ran this command to save the yolo_custom-30.meta file to built_graph/yolo_custom.pb file:

```
   python3 flow --model cfg/yolo_custom.cfg --load -1 --savepb
```

result is:

> Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
>   Finished in 9.207940340042114s
>   Rebuild a constant version ...
>   Done

now when I test my images stored in sample_img folder using this command:

```
   python3 flow --pbLoad built_graph/yolo_custom.pb  --metaLoad built_graph/yolo_custom.meta --imgdir sample_img/
```

the sample_img/out folder that contains the output images has got incomplete/lossy image that contains only few pixels of original image. and the json file contains a lot of bounding box locaions.

this doesn't make sense. I'm very confused. Please help he understand where I'm missing the point.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your loss is too high. It is still underfitting, so hence your output might have multiple predictions. To understand this, check your json file, it might have thousands of predictions. Hence train the model for more epochs with a small subset of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the observations, It did have many predictions as I trained more, it got better. But I trained for only one class. I'm not sure how it'd turn for training multiple new classes though.